# How to add first numbers and skip the next numbers and print total sum

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, sum

I am new to Java, and I have code that print the sum of 1 to 100.

Now, I need to add the first 10 numbers and skip the next 10 until it reaches 100, then it should print the sum of 2275 only by using the following:

- `for`-loop
- Two `if`-statements
- Three Variables: `x` `y` `sum`

This is the [Flowchart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HLncrtkl7AbpPAbiyFb2XadkiJQdhFpP/view?usp=sharing) that I need to follow, but I can't understand. I tried to code it with `if`-statements, but it only prints the sum of 1 to 100.

Can someone help me? How can I implement the `if`-statement? Is it inside the for loop or should be outside the for loop?

Here is my code, this one prints: `4950`

```
int x = 0;
int sum = 0;

for (int y=0; y<=99; y++)
{
   sum = sum + y;
}
  System.out.println("The total sum is: "+sum); // print: 4950
```

This is the one with `if`-statement, but prints: `2450`

```
    int x = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int y=0; y<=99; y++)
    {
       
      if (x<=10)
        {
          sum = sum + y;
          y++;
        }
      if (x==0)
        {
         x++;
        }
    }
      System.out.println("The total sum is: "+sum); // print: 2450
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a loop you need to increment x and y by one. While `x <= 10` condition is true `sum = sum + y`. If x is going to 20 then x is become 0 and again this `x <= 10` is become true.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int sum = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            x++;
            y++;

            if(x <= 10)
            {
                sum += y;
            }
            
            if(x == 20)
            {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The total sum is: "+sum);
    }
}
```